# How to solve this exponential equation? $2^{2x}3^x=4^{3x+1}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I haven't been able to find the correct answer to this exponential equation:

$$\eqalign{
2^{2x}3^x&=4^{3x+1}\\
2^{2x} 3^x &=  2^2 \times 2^x \times 3^x\\
4^{3x+1} &= 4^3 \times 4^x \times 4\\
6^x \times 4 &= 4^x \times 256\\
x\log_6 6 + \log_6 4 &= x\log_64 + \log_6 256\\
x + \log_6 4 &= x\log_64 + \log_6 256\\
x-x\log_6 4 &= \log_6 256 - \log_6 4\\
x(1-\log_6 4) &= \log_6 256 - \log_6 4\\
x &= \dfrac{\log_6 256 - \log_6 4}{1-\log_6 4}\\
x &= 10.257}$$

so when I checked the answer I wasn't able to make them equal, I have tried variants of this method but I feel I'm missing something..

Comment: Be careful ! you have applied several times the formula $\color{red}{a^{bc}=a^ba^c}$ which is wrong ! (For instance $2^{2x}$ is not in general equal to $2^22^x=2^{2\color{red}+x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the logarithm : you get
$$ 2x\ln 2+x\ln 3=(3x+1)\ln 4$$
Then solve this linear equation to get the desired result.

Added in edit

First use $\ln4=2\ln2$ and then group the $x$ together on the left-hand side.
$$ x\times(2\ln2+\ln3-6\ln2)=2\ln2.$$

Now simplify and divide
$$ x=\frac{2\ln2}{\ln3-4\ln2}\simeq -0.82814445.$$

Comment: This is the method i wanted to initially use but I didnt know where to go after this step to get x on it's own, could you show this?

Comment: OK, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Can I ask where the -6 ln 2 is from?

Comment: The $-6\ln2$ comes from the $(3x+1)\ln4$ in the first equation. Replace $\ln4$ by $2\ln2$ you get $(6x+2)\ln2$. Then move the $6x\ln2$ to the left-hand side.

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake in your first steps.

It should be :

$$4^{3x+1}= (4^3)^x \cdot 4$$

$$2^{2x} 3^x= 4^x 3^x$$

Comment: Who did upvote this horrible thing ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust ,What's wrong with my error spotting?

Comment: Ha ha, you just fixed it!

Comment: @YvesDaoust , It was a typo -.- I typed the answer fast :p made a small error :p I guess the voter went through roughly too :)

Comment: Yep, the upvote was a typo as well.

Comment: @YvesDaoust , haha nice one (y) ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem with your solution might be here:

$2^2x * 3^x => 2^2 * 2*x * 3^x$

$4^{3x+1} => 4^3 * 4^x * 4$

since $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$ and not $a^b * a^c$. So for instance:

$4^{3x+1} => 4^x * 4^x * 4^x * 4$

Answer (score 3):

$$2^{2x}3^x=4^{3x+1},$$
$$(e^{\log2})^{2x}(e^{\log3})^x=(e^{\log4})^{3x+1},$$
$$e^{2x\log2}e^{x\log3}=e^{(3x+1)\log4},$$
$$e^{2x\log2+x\log3}=e^{(3x+1)\log4}.$$
Take the log,
$$2x\log2+x\log3=(3x+1)\log4,$$and
$$x=\frac{\log4}{2\log2+\log3-3\log4}=\frac1{\frac{\log3}{\log4}-2}.$$

Comment: (upvoted!) ;))))

Comment: This is the way I initially wanted to do it but couldn't really get past your first step after putting the logs in form  a log (b). Could you maybe show how you went from the first step to the second and third?

Comment: Sorry I meant after the first step, to get x on its own

Comment: This is elementary, put some effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your second step goes wrong

$2^{2x}=2^x+2^x$ but not $2^2*2^x$

simpler way

$3^x=(2^2)^{3x+1}/2^{2x}$

$3^x=2^{6x+2-2x}$

$3^x=2^{4x+2}$

Then apply log to the base e on both sides and use your calculator.